# How to partition and rearrange list values using a set of lists in python?

Tags: python, list

The lists 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', and 'v4' are standard lists.

```
v1 = ['Elisa', 'Liza', 'Izabela', 'Elisabeth', 'Elizabeth', 'Lisa', 'Lizzy', 'Isabella', 'Isabelle', 'Isabela', 'Liz']
v2 = ['Abbey', 'Abbie', 'Abigail', 'Abby', 'Gail']
v3 = ['Jonathan', 'Jon', 'John', 'Jonny', 'Johnny', 'Nathan']
v4 = ['Alejandra','Alexandra','Alexis','Alya','Alexa','Lexi','Allie','Ally']
```

**List 'a' is given as input:**

```
a = ['Jonathan', 'Jim', 'Jennifer', 'Alya', 'Renee', 'Natasha', 'Phil', 'Lisa', 'Joe', 'Ana', 'Paul', 'Gail', 'Roderick', 'Patricia']
```

There will be always just one value from each standard list appearing anywhere in list 'a'.
The expected output is a list that will have sets of values partitioned by values that are found in list 'a' from lists 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4'. Position of these sets will be rearranged in the order of 'v1' value set -> 'v2' value set -> 'v3' value set -> 'v4' value set

**Expected output**

```
a_out = ['Lisa', 'Joe', 'Ana', 'Paul', 'Gail', 'Roderick', 'Patricia', 'Jonathan', 'Jim', 'Jennifer', 'Alya', 'Renee', 'Natasha', 'Phil']
```

Image for partition and set arrangement reference -

[image]

*Example 2:*

**Input**

```
a = ['Abby', 'Robin', 'Natasha', 'Frank', 'Ana', 'Jennifer', 'Elizabeth', 'Tanya', 'Jim', 'Will', 'Rob', 'Joe', 'Alexa', 'Roger', 'Adam', 'Paul', 'James', 'Kara', 'John', 'Jeff', 'Rick', 'Steve']
```

**Expected output**

```
a_out = ['Elizabeth', 'Tanya', 'Jim', 'Will', 'Rob', 'Joe', 'Abby', 'Robin', 'Natasha', 'Frank', 'Ana', 'Jennifer', 'John', 'Jeff', 'Rick', 'Steve', 'Alexa', 'Roger', 'Adam', 'Paul', 'James', 'Kara']
```

Image for partition and set arrangement reference -

[image]

How to obtain such results using python lists?

Comment: Can you explain why for your first example `Phil` would not be the last element in the output?

Comment: @JRoseI I forgot to add it. I've made the changes. Phil should be last element in the output. Thank you for highlighting and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
tmp = {}
for i, lst in enumerate([v1, v2, v3, v4], 1):
    for w in lst:
        tmp[w] = i

a_new, last = [], 0
for i, w in enumerate(a):
    last = tmp.get(w, last)
    a_new.append(last)

print([w for w, _ in sorted(zip(a, a_new), key=lambda k: k[1])])
```

Prints:

```py
['Lisa', 'Joe', 'Ana', 'Paul', 'Gail', 'Roderick', 'Patricia', 'Jonathan', 'Jim', 'Jennifer', 'Alya', 'Renee', 'Natasha', 'Phil']
```

---

Note: If the first name(s) is not found in v1/v2/v3 or v4 it is placed at the beginning of the output list.

Comment: In the example `Phil` is not part of any partition, which I am still trying to figure out myself.

Comment: @JRose It's probably a typo. Based on the logic Phil should be the last element.

Comment: My solution got the same result as yours and I think you are correct but I wanted to make sure OP didn't leave out some instructions on how to make partitions. Anyways, your code is a lot nicer than mine so I will not be sharing my answer.

Comment: @JRose Share it, it's always good to see alternatives. I'll upvote it.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, I forgot to add Phil in the expected output. I've made the changes. Phil should be last element in the output. The solution you have provided solves the problem I had. Thanks a lot for this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative implementation. The basic logic is you want to first find which elements of `a` are in `v`, then you find where each partition starts and ends, then construct `a_out` with these indexes.

```
v1 = ['Elisa', 'Liza', 'Izabela', 'Elisabeth', 'Elizabeth', 'Lisa', 'Lizzy', 'Isabella', 'Isabelle', 'Isabela', 'Liz']
v2 = ['Abbey', 'Abbie', 'Abigail', 'Abby', 'Gail']
v3 = ['Jonathan', 'Jon', 'John', 'Jonny', 'Johnny', 'Nathan']
v4 = ['Alejandra','Alexandra','Alexis','Alya','Alexa','Lexi','Allie','Ally']

a = ['Abby', 'Robin', 'Natasha', 'Frank', 'Ana', 'Jennifer', 'Elizabeth', 'Tanya', 'Jim', 'Will', 'Rob', 'Joe', 'Alexa', 'Roger', 'Adam', 'Paul', 'James', 'Kara', 'John', 'Jeff', 'Rick', 'Steve']

a_set, v_contains = set(a), []

for lst in [v1, v2, v3, v4]:
    v_contains += [val for val in lst if val in a_set]

v_contains_set, v_contains_index, a_out = set(v_contains), [a.index(partition_start) for partition_start in v_contains], []

for idx in v_contains_index:
    if max(v_contains_index) != idx:
        a_out += a[idx:min(filter(lambda i: i > idx, v_contains_index))]
    else:
        a_out += a[idx:]

print(a_out)
```

Comment: This method also works. Thanks a lot for this. :)